# Laptop battery after 100% charge says 67% remaining

Tags: battery, toshiba-laptop

In April 2019 bought a new battery for my Toshiba Satellite P55W C5200X from Amazon. I put the battery in on August 10, 2019. But after charging the battery says 67% after I fully charge it. Also last night after installing it, the battery initially was around half, then a few minutes later it says 9%. From more than 50% to only 9%. Is the battery defective? Did I wait too late to install it? Should I just buy a new battery directly from Toshiba?

Comment: Not all batteries are of equal quality, sounds like a really cheaply made lion battery, return it to Amazon and buy a different brand of battery.

Answer (score 1):

Waiting to install it likely had *no* impact -- Li batteries hold charge for *years*.

First thing, try [resetting battery charging](https://superuser.com/questions/1305783/battery-not-charging-laptop-only-works-when-plugged). The following applies to Windows OS:

- In *Hardware Manager*, delete the ACPI-compliant control method driver.
- Shut down completely (not hibernate).
- Unplug the power supply.
- Remove the battery.
- Hold down the power switch for 30 seconds to drain any residual charge.
- Put hings together and reboot: Windows should reinstall the driver by itself.

If that doesn't help, return the battery -- hopefully, Amazon would accept that, though a few months late. As for buying a new one, I've had good luck with third-party batteries; perhaps try another brand.