# Battery drops to 0 from 46% despite having equal design and full charge capacity

Tags: battery, dell-latitude, windows-10-v1909

I bought a used dell latitude e7450 yesterday. The laptop works fine except the battery drops to 0% from 46% really quickly and it shuts down without warning. The battery report says that the design capacity and full charge capacity are both 38,850 mWh which does not seem to make sense. I am attaching the battery report with the post in case additional information is required.

[Battery wear level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxn7K.png)

[Power states over the last 3 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrMLz.png)

Comment: The battery is old and needs replaced.

Comment: @Moab But then why does it show 0% wear?

Comment: Perhaps update the power driver and see, in Device Manager, if you can update the battery. It does not show any use in the software but the computer itself is not new.

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened it up and verified if it's a genuine Dell battery?  You may also want to boot in to Linux and see if the behaviour is the same plus you'll get additional battery info from there.
Personally if the laptop is over 2years old I'd just replace the battery regardless even if it's for an unbranded equivalent.

Comment: It *could* be a bad battery, but try resetting the charging state before replacing the battery: https://superuser.com/questions/1305783/battery-not-charging-laptop-only-works-when-plugged