# Zenbook laptop does not fully charge, saying `67% available (plugged in)`

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, asus-laptop, zenbook

I'm using a UX330U Zenbook and I can't get my battery to be 100% charged. It keeps saying `67% available (plugged in)`. I'm using Win 10 and I've completed all the "forced" updates by freakin Microsoft. I followed the 2 tips here -> https://www.drivethelife.com/windows-10/fix-laptop-battery-not-charging-to-100-windows-10.html and none worked. Can't do tip #3 cos Zenbook battery is non-removable.

Battery report via `powercfg` command says...

```
2020-07-1019:31:57  Active  AC  67 %    19,115 mWh
```

Comment: How old is your laptop?? All batteries will wear out over time. Reduced capacity is the result. It will get even worse with time.

Comment: @svin83 Good thought. It's 2 to 3 years old.

Comment: Try resetting battery charging before buying a new one. See https://superuser.com/questions/1305783/battery-not-charging-laptop-only-works-when-plugged answer. Let me know if that works.

Comment: If you have the skills you could buy a replacement battery online. That is way cheaper than having a technician replace it. HOWEVER: Do NOT change worn out Li-Ion cells if you don't know how dangerous they can be, and how to properly and safely handle and dispose of them.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The battery can't be removed. So I can't follow https://superuser.com/questions/1305783/battery-not-charging-laptop-only-works-when-plugged

Comment: @svin83 The battery can't be removed. So I can't replace the batt i think.

Comment: Everything CAN be removed if you have the skills and tools, but do remember what I said about Lithium cells above.

Comment: See https://www.insidemylaptop.com/taking-apart-asus-zenbook-ux330-ux330u-ux330ua/ if you have the technical skills.

Comment: Discharge the battery to 10%, then see if it charges past 67%.

Comment: Probably a dead end - but have you had a look in your BIOS? Some laptops have different battery modes, and its conceivable your laptop is keeping the battery at 67% to prolong the battery life. (My Dell laptop does this)

Comment: @davidgo Interesting, didn't know that. I'll look at the BIOS.

Comment: @Moab this doesn't work after trying

Answer (score -1):

Mine was doing the same. I believe it has something to do with the Asus battery saver power plan. I went into the Control Panel, Power Options and swapped to a "Balanced" vs "Asus Recommended" and it charged all the way up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).