# Laptop charging indicator switches between fully charged and charging

Tags: laptop, battery, power, charging

I have a [HP 15 bs024nq](https://support.hp.com/ro-en/document/c05888631) that is 2 years old, I got it in September of 2018.

It started happening a week ago. When I charge my laptop(no matter the operating system, it happens on GNU/Linux and Windows, I tested it, I have dual boot) when reaching the  >70 percent when charging things start to go crazy and slow.

The indicator that shows that it's charging switches between white(it's fully charged) and orange(it's charging) modes.

I noticed that the OS's seem to tell me it's charging.
I run a command to see details about the battery.

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ACAD
  native-path:          ACAD
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 17 Jul 2020 10:20:12 PM EEST (1373 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               Hewlett-Packard
  model:                PABAS0241231
  serial:               41167
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 17 Jul 2020 10:41:55 PM EEST (70 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              25.9296 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         28.8204 Wh
    energy-full-design:  41.61 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.219 W
    voltage:             16.26 V
    time to full:        13.2 hours
    percentage:          89%
    capacity:            69.2632%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1595014915  0.219   charging

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 17 Jul 2020 10:41:55 PM EEST (70 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              25.9296 Wh
    energy-full:         28.8204 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.219 W
    time to full:        13.2 hours
    percentage:          89%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.11
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

The charger has no problems, I tested without the battery and the laptop run just fine without any sudden shut down and also it charges the laptop until the previously mentioned level.

I don't have problems with the power supply as I have another laptop that is charging correctly and without problems.

I suspect it's the battery's fault.

Also, the laptop automatically shuts down when reaching 30 %.

I tried to cycle it, charged it fully 100% and after that wait for it to be discharged, also entered the BIOS and waited until it was not able too power up.
I did not let it in this state(I know it's bad for batteries to let them in this sensible state) and put it on charge and didn't touch it until it reached 100 %.

What could be the problem ? Can you give me an explanation to this ? My intention is to buy another battery but I am somehow suspicious that could not be the battery fault. Let me know what you think !

Comment: Some laptops have a charging mode to extend battery life by only charging to 70 or 80% of full charge. This is useful if used mainly running on AC, though it shortens the run time on battery alone. Has it been turned on? Also, try resetting the charge state: https://superuser.com/questions/1305783/battery-not-charging-laptop-only-works-when-plugged

Comment: This didn't happen to me before ! I will try, I also ordered a new battery