# Dell laptop battery dies down too quickly off late

Tags: laptop, battery

I am using Dell Inspiron 15 3567, and I think I wasn't charging it the proper way - I switch on the power before I insert the charger into my PC. I thought that was the proper way so it was something I usually do. I realized that  was not the right way so I changed. **Here lies my problem**.
*My battery used to take me along for 4+ hours but off late, not even up to 10 minutes. My battery dies down too quickly and I don't know what and how to fix it.* Please any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with starting your computer on battery and then plugging in the charger. This is a correct way. So is plugging in first and then starting up.

Leave the charger plugged in overnight (even with the computer OFF).  See the next day whether the battery has charged and lasts.

Also make sure the charger is working (charges from orange to green over a few hours)

If everything above is OK and the battery does not last, the battery is likely due for replacement.

Comment: Before buying a battery, reset the charging cycle: https://superuser.com/questions/1305783/battery-not-charging-laptop-only-works-when-plugged

Comment: That does appear to be the case