# My laptop shuts down unexpectedly (no BSOD) when i unplug it from wall power, and battery seems like it's dying

Tags: windows-10, laptop, power-supply, crash, battery

My Asus vivobook X540UA (windows 10) suddenly shuts down without warning (no BSOD) when I unplug it from wall power, however I can still use the battery if I turn it on while it's unplugged - but then the laptop randomly crashes doing mundane tasks.

I used the Asus battery health charging utility and locked my battery's max charge to 60% 3 years ago because I keep it plugged in almost all the time (I know, bad habits die hard).

I started seeing the problem around the summer period...
I tried following guides to fix the problem but had no luck resolving the issue.
The laptop now shuts down when switching between wall power and the battery and at random times when using the battery alone.

I just made a battery report today and there's a pretty big difference between the max factory capacity and the current capacity of the battery.
Is there anything I can do in software or is my battery dying?
[(battery report and energy report attached in this link)](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1ectt5jmazeGpJg-fHRcrLXXwcKLSxPSy)

Comment: 1. Try resetting battery charging: https://superuser.com/questions/1305783/battery-not-charging-laptop-only-works-when-plugged 2. Replace the battery, if that doesn't work - ads online list third-party batteries for ~$US33.

Answer (score 0):

> I used the asus battery health charging utility and locked my
> battery's max charge to 60% 3 years ago

That was a good thing to do (I do this myself).

But Battery Threshold software does not stop a battery from wearing out. All batteries wear out in time. 30 to 48 months is a decent lifespan for a battery.

You can try charging to 100% and then re-enable the threshold software to see if that helps.

> Is there anything I can do in software or is my battery dying?

Most likely, the battery now needs to be replaced.

I hope this helps.