# Windows 10 hibernates because of the battery

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, power, hibernate

And by "actively" I do mean I'm typing or moving the mouse.
When it happens, windows shows me a dialog box. But before I can read it, the pc is going into hibernation.

I ran *powercfg /sleepstudy*, which gave me this result at the time it happened:

```
        START TIME  DURATION    STATE       ENTRY REASON    EXIT REASON    % CAPACITY REMAINING AT START
2021-01-2521:31:07  0:01:04     Hibernate   Battery         Unknown        -
```

I've tried the following steps:

- dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth
- sfc /scannow
- Appx: disabled development mode (not applicable, but that's what docter google said)

Last time it happened, the event log showed me the following error:

- Provider: *DeviceSetupManager*
- ID: *131*
- Message: *Metadata staging failed, result=0x80004005 for container '{61A8331A-E61B-11EA-B197-0028F837B901}'*

So there's no event that explains the hibernate. A warning in the same minute it happend reads: `Media disconnected on NIC /DEVICE/{F56CA76B-204A-42A5-88CA-E16761AA86EB} (Friendly Name: Microsoft Netork Adapter Multiplexor Driver`

Has anyone experienced this issue. Is it really the battery? The power adapter should be able to supply enough power. The battery is non-removable.

System information: **latest build, all (driver-)updates installed**

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.19042 Build 19042
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Manufacturer Notebook
System Model    P870KM_KM1
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  Not Applicable
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz, 4201 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. 5.12, 11/07/2017
SMBIOS Version  3.0
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode   UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Notebook
BaseBoard Product   P870KM_KM1
Platform Role   Mobile
Secure Boot State   Off
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state, "The power adapter should be able to supply enough power," and that is true *if the battery is not shorted internally*. If so, it would bring down the bus voltage  below what the system requires.

Check the battery condition with a utility such as free [HWinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/download/):

[image: HWinfo Battery data]

Compare the current voltage to that specified for the laptop's battery; if significantly less, you have a few options:

1. Try discharging and recharging the battery as shown in the [Clevo P870KM manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1288469/Clevo-P870km.html?page=112#manual).
2. Try [resetting the ACP battery charging mechanism](https://superuser.com/questions/1305783/battery-not-charging-laptop-only-works-when-plugged).
3. Replace the battery. If you use the device mostly on AC power, you might use an inexpensive third-party battery. See the [Clevo P870KM Service Manual for changing out the battery](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1300989/Clevo-P870km.html?page=29#manual).

Comment: Wow, you really put some thought into this :) Thanks! I'll check everything you mentioned and get back to you. I sure hope it's not shorted battery

Comment: Battery: 40W when idle and 115W when surfing the web. The only odd thing I noticed is HWInfo tells me my fully charged capacity is 212mWh (designed: 89208mWh). The conclusion appears to be my battery is dying? When surfing the web, the remaining time drops to 30 minutes or less.

Comment: That 40W/115W is *power drain*, and a battery with only 212 mWh *capacity* would only be be able to power the laptop for **a few seconds**. Try resetting ACP charging, and if that doesn't help, a new battery is needed.

Comment: Alright, thanks again. I just tried draining the battery. Launching The Witcher 3 didn't even get me to the main menu... so case closed! One extra question tho, are there advantages for taking the battery out of my system since it's of no use to me anymore?

Comment: Did you try resetting the charging system? That is *different from* draining the battery.

Comment: I'll be dusting out my hardware in two weeks, so I'll remember to try resetting. The battery is built-in, so it's a bit of a hassle to open up the case just for that. I'll definitely get back to you on that