Bought an X220 Lenovo in a good shape. Used it for a couple of weeks. But for two days I can't load the battery
Bought an X220 Lenovo in a good shape. Used it for a couple of weeks. But for two days I can't load the battery. I use a SANYO 45N1172. It's stuck on 48% and shuts down if i take the power supply off. I also use Linux Mint.
Can someone help me?

Before buying a battery, try resetting the laptops charging:https://superuser.com/questions/1305783/battery-not-charging-laptop-only-works-when-plugged . It might or might not help,  but costs nothing.

@DrMoishePippik Thanks, i have to figure out how to test that on Linux Mint
