Why HP Windows 10 laptop is not starting without charging cable
I have a HP Windows 10 laptop. I was reinstalling Windows yesterday so I left the charging plug on and today when I was using it, it suddenly got shutdown so plugged the charger.  As you may know there is a small light in side of the charging port it was red. It means it was not charged so I put it on charging.
After a few minutes I came back and saw that the LED was white which means it's fully charged.  When I unplugged it and clicked the start button it didn't start. When I plugged it back in and tried to start it, it started.  I checked the battery status it was showing 0% Plugged and  also when I pressed start button BIOS showed up. I don't remember exactly what it said but there is something wrong with the battery and it should be replaced for proper performance.

This is exactly how a worn-out laptop battery behaves. Basically, it has degraded so far that there is essentially no useful capacity left between the minimum-voltage cutoff and the maximum charge the battery can still take. Laptop batteries are essentially wear items: each charge/discharge cycle will wear them down, and they will also slowly degrade on their own as time passes even if unused, because of the chemistry involved.

As said, it might be a failing battery. It could also be that charging need s to be reset: see https://superuser.com/questions/1305783/battery-not-charging-laptop-only-works-when-plugged
